# Windows 10 spell check adds misspelled words

Tags: windows, skype, spell-check, autocorrect

Is there a way to review the alterations to spell check in Windows? I'm noticing more and more that typos are somehow getting in when using Skype (I have the "Auto correct and highlight misspelled words" checked). The most recent is "aroudn"; Firefox shows it with the red squiggly, MS Word objects to it as well, but Skype is completely fine with it. I was under the impression that Skype would use Office's spellcheck, since they're connected, but this does not appear to be so.

That being said, I'm not really sure where this data is being kept. In Settings->Devices->Typing, both auto correct and highlight misspelled words are toggled on.

Anyone know where to access the Skype dictionary that is okay with my typos?

Answer (score 0):

In general, Skype’s spell check feature is turned on.

We can go to Options\IM, make a tick before Check spelling as I type option.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more seeking where to find the dictionaries involved, especially in regards to Skype.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the exact same issue; disappointed to see no one has answered yet.

Accidentally added a misspelled word to skype and everything I find online only talks about how to correct the custom dictionaries for other M$ products, which Skype doesn't seem to utilize.

*EDIT*

I was able to locate it finally: %appdata%\Microsoft\Spelling\en-US

Delete all the files there and that should clear out any custom words added to the dictionary (worked for me at least).